# USB mouse not working

Tags: drivers, usb, mouse, parted-magic

Every time I plug in any wired mouse recently, I get similar to the below on `VCS1`:

> [1443270.286164] usb 6-1: new low-speed USB device number 15 using uhci_hcd
>   [1443270.454270] usb 6-1: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0083
>   [1443270.461874] usb 6-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
>   [1443270.469328] usb 6-1: Product: Basic Optical Mouse
>   [1443270.476877] usb 6-1: Manufacturer: Microsoft
>   [1443270.501140] input: Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/input/input26
>   [1443270.509327] hid-generic 0003:045E:0083.000F: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0

.. but no mouse functionality.

The last time [I spent some trying to solve this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89138/take-copy-of-tty0-text), the final line that is now missing from the above, was `No input driver specified, ignoring this device`

I haven't tried a computer reboot, because I am interested in using this opportunity to become more acquainted with the mouse subsystem(s) of Linux.

Found [Restart USB mouse driver?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49272/restart-usb-mouse-driver) while writing up this question, but not sure how to try steps 2 & 3 of what this OP tried (Have restarted X, however - No change).

What should I look at next?

Comment: You should look at your X configuration (if you still have one, and its not all auto-probed), and possibly udev. Does X show anything in its logs? What does `xinput list` show?

Comment: Sorry - What should I be looking for in the X Config file (Which is where?); Where is the X logs, and the xinput.list?

Comment: X config would be in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`. X logs are `/var/log/Xorg.*.log`. `xinput list` is a command you run inside an xterm (or gnome-terminal, or konsole, etc.)

Comment: By the way, please remember to go and [accept](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer that you got to your other question. Assuming it answered it that is but your comments seem to imply that it did.

Comment: derobert - I don't have a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (./X11 Directory just contains `XVESA`, `app-defaults`, `fs` & `xkb` directories); `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` only contains entries about the touchpad; Running `xinput` in ROXTerm reports `command not found` @terdon - Unfortunately there is still clarifications in the comments, that haven't been answered, and feel that would complete the answer to the question, being the reason I haven't done so yet.

Comment: @user66001 Not sure which distro you're running, but it should have a package for xinput. Install it. [BTW: If you leave off the @-sign, I don't get notified of new comments. Yeah, the limit of only one person notified per message is annoying...]

Comment: @derobert - Okay. Can I ask what `xinput` is likely to give me, in the way of help on this issue? Sorry about the lack of the @ - Had thought when writing my response, that it was a comment to your answer :( Agree on the 1 person notified - I really do wonder why this rule exists.

Comment: @user66001 xinput will tell you which input devices X sees, and what its using them for. Here are examples from two of my machines: http://pastebin.com/kn0wYYRr

Comment: @derobert - Thanks. Just out of curiosity - Is there any other way of getting this info?

Comment: Probably there is some other way. Is there some reason you can't install xinput?

Comment: @derobert - The problem happens to have occurred on a live distro, which is running a large recovery process on, but has no package manager. After doing a bit of research through google, I couldn't tell if this tool is just something you run, or there is more intertwining with the OS involved.