# Why does going into text mode and then back to graphical mode fix a mouse disappearance?

Tags: linux, drivers, usb, mouse

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/351372/250208) to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49272/250208) fixed my mouse cursor which had disappeared and was not responding to inputs. The answer suggested going into text mode (using  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> ) and immediately back to graphical mode (using  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) and it worked perfectly well.  Why does this happen though, does the interface get restarted or something similar when we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, the *display* of the mouse cursor is implemented as a hardware overlay a.k.a. "sprite".  There is an X.org option called HWCursor (hardware cursor).

So resetting all the graphics modes may fix an error in the hardware cursor configuration.